# separate the vector into real and imaginary parts

Tags: complex-analysis

How does one separate below vectors into the proper form? I've tried everything I could think of, including suggested answers below that should work but don't.

[image]

[image]

c +/- di is required form. Thanks.

Comment: Edit: added better picture of two vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vectors now appear to be $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \frac{-1\pm i}{2} \end{bmatrix}$, which can be rewritten as $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \frac{-1}{2} \end{bmatrix} \pm i\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}$.  I'm not 100% sure that this is what you are looking for, but it's my best try.

Comment: This worked, writing it as (-1+/-i)/2 makes it clear. Thanks / voted